# How can I render custom google maps tiles with mapnik?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, mapnik

I'm currently developing my own little GIS service, that displays custom computed information on a google map.

As you can see, I'm loading a custom tile overlay, where I renderd the information in a color scale. The problem is with the Google Maps texts for places like Berlin. Those are now partially covered by my tiles and hard to read. I would like to have the text displayed above my tiles.

Can I render the Google Maps texts for places and streets using mapnik? Or can I put my custom tiles between the text and the map image (but I dont think those two information are splitted into separated images, so it might not be possible)?

[image: Current snapshot]

Comment: [Ogofo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/125297/ogofo), unfortunately, you cannot apply mapnik as a render engine for Google Maps, because their data is protected. However, what you can do - customize Google Maps through API, more information is [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling). So you probably have to play around with Google Maps styling and adjust labelling.

Comment: Removing them makes the map look cleaner. But I would like to keep the names of streets and citys. Is there a possibility to get the data from OSM and render this data via mapnik?

Comment: [Ogofo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/125297/ogofo), the answer is definitely yes, but the workflow depends on your programming capabilities.

Comment: I would give it a try. Currently I'm having a shape file with my data saved in an dbf filem I'm using mapnik with the python bindings.The first question I got is how to export the OSM data (names of streets and citys) into a readable shape file?

Comment: [Ogofo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/125297/ogofo), first of all, you need to extract OSM data, I may suggest this resource: [Geofabrik](https://download.geofabrik.de/) or you can try to export directly from [OSM official website](https://www.openstreetmap.org/export#map=12/52.5167/13.4497), but be careful the possible export zoom level for Berlin starts with 12, inclusive. Later on, you need to convert osm data into .shp, more information you can find on [OpenStreetMap Wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shapefiles).

Comment: [Ogofo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/125297/ogofo), I have found [a nice solution, e.g. MyGeodata Converter](https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/) for you, which can handle the area of Berlin easily and provide you with the export choices.

Comment: @TarasDubrava Thanks for your help. I'm currently using mapnik and a PostGIS database. It works "OK", but its not perfect yet. A paid solution is not what I want, but thank you for your effort!